# Check if array is NULL at specific index in iOS

Tags: ios, indexing, null, nsarray

I have an arra which contains be 5 values. But I know at least on one index the value will be NULL. I've tried something like this

```
if ([array objectAtIndex:2]!=nil) //Right now array contains 5 values in total
{
       //do something
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I know that at index 2 there is no value but still goes INTO the "if" Statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work. Checking `!= nil` is unnecessary, and you can use array index operator, so you can write

```
if (array[2]) {
    ...
}
```

If the code goes into the conditional, there is an object at `array[2]`. Add `NSLog` call to see what's there:

```
if (array[2]) {
    NSLog(@"Element 2 is '%@'", array[2]);
    // ... The rest of your code
}
```

> I get `Element 2 is "` output

Then it's an empty string. Use

```
if ([array[2] length]) {
    ...
}
```

to check for it.

Comment: Seeing your reputation I know you can't be wrong. But it's not working either :(

Comment: @Rahul It looks like your element is an empty string then.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to check it then?

Comment: @Rahul If your array contains only `NSString`s, then the condition `if ([array[2] length])` should work.

Comment: I am sure you are a busy man. But coz of you it finally worked :). Thank you so damn much for your time . Was trying it from last 45 mins :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check object exist at index

```
if ([array objectAtIndex:2]) 
{
   //object Exist
}
else
{

  //Object not Exist
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Still going into the "if" statement.

Comment: then there is some string my be "null" exist you can print that value in log and check whether it is nil or a string "null"

Comment: I have use this code NSString *str=nil;
    NSLog(@"String %@",str); and out is "String (null)" and you are saying nothing exist how is it possible?

Comment: Because you are using NSString and I am using NSArray

Comment: then You can use this string.length>0 then exist otherwise not

Comment: Yeah thanx mate for your time. It's working. But since @dasblinkenlight answered it before you. I am voting his answer. But thanx a lot for your help.